# declaring a list from htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a declaration

`List<Object> links = this.page.getByXPath("//[@id=\"body\"]/section/ol//@href");`

the list itself should be a list of HtmlUnit DomAttr objects.

and the error that is thrown to me is

```
Error:(42, 46) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>
```

I do not understand the java capture#1 of ? part of this Error. Could someone tell me how to correctly declare the list?

EDIT: the output of the returned list `this.page.getByXpath(..)` is

```
[DomAttr[name=href value=/news/uk/woman-nearly-blinded-by-christmas-card-glitter-which-gave-her-herpeslike-infection-a3730441.html], DomAttr[name=href value=/sport/football/crystal-palace-double-injury-blow-jason-puncheon-scott-dann-out-for-rest-of-season-a3730461.html], DomAttr[name=href value=/sport/football/arsenal-boss-arsene-wenger-says-refereeing-in-england-is-stuck-in-the-dark-ages-and-that-move-to-var-a3730271.html], DomAttr[name=href value=/sport/football/west-ham-news-david-moyes-brands-andy-carroll-unbeatable-in-the-air-a3730466.html]....]
```

Comment: What is declared return type of `getByXpath` method?

Comment: edited the list that is returned. It seems to be a list of DomAttr objects

Comment: No, no. I meant *declared* return type. When you read documentation of that method you see how it was declared and what it promise to return. What *type* does this method "declare/promise" to return?

Comment: I think it is  <T> List<T> ?

Comment: actually it says the elements which match the specified XPath expression?

Comment: What is `page` type (how did you declare it) and which version of htmlutil you are using?

Comment: Assuming that `page` is `HtmlPage`, when you invoke `page.getByXPath` it uses code inherited from `DomNode` which in 2.33 is declared as `public <T> List<T> getByXPath(final String xpathExpr)`, but in 2.4 was changed to `public List<?> getByXPath(final String xpathExpr)` which may cause you this problem. If you want to use 2.4 version then you should change `List<Object>` to `List<?>`.

Comment: understood, thank you